# Count items in array based on specific keywords within the elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 3 columns:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Tag

in a google spreadsheet

123456 - Jack - Dec 2019;Jan 2020

within the 3rd column tag I have values like this:

- Dec 2019;Jan 2020
- Oct 2019;Nov 2020; Jan 2020;
- Nov 2019;Jan 2020
- Apr 2019;May 2020
- Apr 2020

My final purpose is to count with a google script all the elements in column C that are from  a specific month AND year and put the totals in another sheet.

I saw that when I use .getValues the array created does not contain anymore those values, they are converted into dates

All the solutions I found are too difficult for me -

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it need to be with [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)?

Because you can do what you are looking to do with formulas, I believe:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y9zslQC00uV6FMe9ExuqptH6n9pz1zpfRVDq1XU-ayc/edit?usp=sharing

like in cell B11: `=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$7,"*" & D14 & "*")`

[image]

I can also probably give you a [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) solution if you are keen to learn how etc.?

The [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) could look like this:

```js
function countTags() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  
  const Direction= SpreadsheetApp.Direction;
  const cLast = spreadsheet.getRange("C"+(spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();

  //var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  //Logger.log(range);

  const countObj = {};

  for (let row = 2; row <= cLast; row++){    
    let tagsArr = spreadsheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue().split(";");
    Logger.log(row, tagsArr)

    for (let tag of tagsArr){
      const trimmedTag = String(tag).trim();

      if (countObj.hasOwnProperty(trimmedTag)){
        countObj[trimmedTag] +=1;
      } else {
        countObj[trimmedTag] =1;
      }
    }        
  }
  const stringObj = JSON.stringify(countObj);        
  Logger.log(stringObj);

  let nextRow = cLast + 11;

  Object.entries(countObj).forEach(([key, val]) => {

    spreadsheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(key);
    spreadsheet.getRange(nextRow, 2).setValue(val);
    nextRow++;

  });

}
```

NOTE: If you know VBA,

this line:

```js
spreadsheet.getRange("C"+(spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();
```

would be equivalent to this in VBA:

```vb
Range(Rows.count,"C").end(xlUp).row
```

See full demo here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y9zslQC00uV6FMe9ExuqptH6n9pz1zpfRVDq1XU-ayc/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Of course. I wanted to ascertain first, if the OP would accept a formula only answer and also copied a link to the Google Spreadsheet. I now added the ``=COUNTIF($C$2:$C$7,"*" & D14 & "*")`` formula and an AppsScript alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes I am learning AppScript - My goal is to have the count of each single tag in the arrays - Like your countIf in column G - Checking your code - Should I add values there or I can run? Tnx a lot

Comment: The code I provided (and the google spreadsheet which I linked), is "ready to go", as long as your data is in the format I showed in the screenshot (ID, Name, Tag(s) are in columns A, B, C). The code looks for the last entry in column C and then loops over from row 2 to that row (``cLast``). It also prints out the results 11 rows below ``cLast``. Please try the code and any questions let me know. If I solved your problem, please consider to up-vote and mark as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: I see, let me run some test and I'll be back in some hours - Thanks

Comment: you said "The code looks for the last entry in column C" - In my case there is no new row unfortunately - Data is dynamically changing every day and there are no cells added into that column -  I would like to set a daily trigger that append data every day in another sheet - I guess I need to work on your line:   const cLast = spreadsheet.getRange("C"+(spreadsheet.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(Direction.UP).getRow();
correct?

Comment: I mean it looks for the last/final row. If you know VBA it would be ``cLast = Range(Rows.count,"C").end(xlUp).row`` So i did not mean a "new" entry or "new" row, I just mean it looks to see how large your data is. i.e. if it has 11 or 12 or 13 rows etc. - makes sense? Did you try the google spreadsheet I liked to? It works perfectly right?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
function findDates() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var ds=sh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  Logger.log(ds);
  var re=new RegExp('Jan2020','g');
  var matches=[...ds.matchAll(re)];
  Logger.log(matches.length);
  return matches.length;
}
```

The string is A1 is `Jan2020;Feb2020;Mar2020;Jan2020`

Comment: Hi Cooper and thanks for your answer - I tried and it works if all the tags are like your Row A1 - In my case the are all in different rows and data is dinamically inserted in that column so the range should adapt to its lenght-  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y9zslQC00uV6FMe9ExuqptH6n9pz1zpfRVDq1XU-ayc/edit#gid=0 in column C you can see how data are ordered in my case!

Comment: Oh thanks for the image when I get back to my laptop I’ll review my code and see if I can improve it for you